# How to trigger a partialview from webgrid row selection by using jquery in Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I was comparing a webgrid and a dropdownbox .I want to trigger a partial view `CoursePartialDemo` via Ajax and has to pass the primary key to the action responsible for partialview.In a dropdownbox i have successfully done it by following Jquery.Similarly if i select a row in a webgrid how can i trigger partial view and pass the primary key  which is  "id" for webgrid.following code is responsible for dropdownbox

```
    <select id="ddlEmployeeCourse">
    @*Iterating Employee ViewModel *@

    @foreach (var emp in Model)
    {
            <option value="@emp.EmpCode">@emp.EmpName</option>           
    }

    </select>

            <h4>Courses Of Selected Employeee</h4>
            <div id="CoursesForEmp">
        </div>
<script>

function getCourseTable(selectedEmpCode) {
    $.ajax({
        // Get Course PartialView
        url: "/Home/CoursePartialDemo",
        type: 'GET',
        data: { EmpCode: selectedEmpCode },
        success: function (data) {
            jQuery("#CoursesForEmp").html(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {              
            alert("Error: Please try again.");
        }
    });
}
</script>

    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#ddlEmployeeCourse").change(function (index) {
            var selectedEmpCode = $(this).val();
            getCourseTable(selectedEmpCode);
        });
    </script>
```

and here is my webgrid code

```
<div id="">
    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
            headerStyle: "header",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
            selectedRowStyle: "select",
            columns: grid.Columns(
            //grid.Column("Id", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.Id)),
            grid.Column("id", "id"),  //primary key
            grid.Column("countryname", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.countryname)),
            grid.Column("continent", "Description", style: "continent"),
            grid.Column("language", "language")
     )) 
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
i have done some changes in webgrid code like shown below

```
@if (grid.HasSelection)
{
    product = (firstmvc4.Models.Country)grid.Rows[grid.SelectedIndex].Value;
    var val = @product.id;
    <script>
        getCourseTable(val)
    </script>

}
```

but javascript function is triggering at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<script>
    getCourseTable(val)
</script>
```

to

```
Html.RenderAction("CoursePartialDemo", new { EmpCode = val });
```

and place inside the `CoursesForEmp` element.

For example:

```
<div id="CoursesForEmp">
@if (grid.HasSelection)
{
    product = (firstmvc4.Models.Country)grid.Rows[grid.SelectedIndex].Value;
    var val = product.id;
    Html.RenderAction("CoursePartialDemo", new { EmpCode = val });
}
</div>
```

I'm not sure if you want to show any product details or employee.